# Moving the toolbar in ReportViewer to the bottom of the page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reportviewer, toolstrip

Relatively new to ReportViewer in WinForms using C#.  What I want to do is to move the toolbar of a report to the bottom.  One method to achieve this was supposedly to just drop a toolstrip on the page and build it from the toolbar.  Seemed relatively easy, just a few lines of code inserted into the Load event:

```
// move the toolbar from the report viewer to the toolstripcontainer
ToolStrip toolStrip = (ToolStrip)FirstTestReport.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true)[0];
toolStrip.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolStrip);
this.FirstTestReport.ShowToolBar = false;
this.toolStripContainer1.Visible = true;
```

Sorta worked.  So, the top toolbar disappeared, but the bottom one never appeared.  While stepping through the code I realized ToolStrip always had a Visible value of False.  I tried to add a line to make it visible (`ToolStrip.Visible = True`) but it didn't run the code; it gave me an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Control.Visible'

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should not set `ShowToolBar` to false, it sets visibility of `reportToolbar` to false which is parent of `toolBar1`. Then as a result, visibility of `toolBar1` will be evaluated as false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With ToolStripContainer**

Also if you want it to be added to the bottom panel of the tool strip container:

```
var toolStrip = (ToolStrip)reportViewer1.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true)[0];
toolStrip.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Visible;
var reportToolbar = toolStrip.Parent;
reportToolbar.Visible = false;
this.toolStripContainer1.BottomToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolStrip);
```

**Without ToolStripContainer**

```
var toolStrip = (ToolStrip)reportViewer1.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true)[0];
toolStip.Parent.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, the first one still didn't work.  But since the second one gave me the result I needed, I'll take it.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I tried both, they worked properly for me. Make sure your test environment is clean. For me, I just added a tool strip panel and didn't change any setting of the control and then run the code which I shared.